# Rails - Combination of Dropdown and Free-Text-Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, combobox, dropdownbox

I am using Rails 4.2.1 and ruby 2.1.6

I am looking for a solution to do the following: 
Have a dropdown containing a list of existing regions (Bundesland).
If I find my region in that list, select from the dropdown and I am fine. 
If I do not find my region, I need to manually type in a new region into a text field. This will create a new entry in the database as well. 
To have this userfriendly and easy to use without switching between fields, I prefer to have this in one field if possible.

Here is the code for my actual dropdown, but without any option for 
free-text and manual input.

```
<br>
= ai3.input :area_id, label: "Bundesland/Kanton", :as => :select, :collection => option_groups_from_collection_for_select( @area_countries_dach, :area_regions, :name, :id, :name)
```

Now this needs to be expanded to a combination of a select-box (dropdown) and a free-text input field.

It would be great to have the user typing into the field the beginning chars for the region. if found, select by click or leaving the field. If not found use the already typed chars for the creation of the new region.

Any ideas on how to solution this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually have a `text_field` appear upon clicking a ***link/button/div*** if the ***region*** is not found in the `drop-down`.

Something like below

```
<div id="show_region" class="btn btn-primary">Cant Find Your Region? Manually Add It Here</div>
<%= ai3.input :some_attribute, :class => 'form-control', :id => 'input_region', placeholder: 'Enter your region' %>
```

***Javacsript***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#input_region').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show_region').click(function() {
    $('#input_region').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

But you ***can't*** save it in the ***same attribute*** ***AFAIK***. You need to have a ***different attribute*** for the `text_field`.

> It would be great to have the user typing into the field the beginning
>   chars for the region. if found, select by click or leaving the field

This needs an ***autocomplete*** `text_field` rather than a normal `text_field`. Take a look [***here***](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) on how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks Pavan.
I am now on testing and playing around with "autocomplete".

Comment: Thanks Pavan.
I need to get this little more complicated.
I am not using (and storing) the text of the region (f.e. Schleswig-Holstein), instead I am using a key (NOT the :id, but a unique specific key like SH). Both values are stored in a table in my db.
And sometimes my values are stored in an array of hashes (f.e. {["Doktor", "Dok"], ["Professor", "Prof"]}. I can figure that out to use the key instead of the full-text.
Also I need to change the style of the new autocomplete-field back to the "standard" input-field, so it has the same look and feel.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As Pavan mentioned, an autocomplete text field works well in this situation. I ran across the same thing recently and used twitter typeahead for it.
https://github.com/yourabi/twitter-typeahead-rails

There's lots of discussion on it elsewhere.